# App Engine DataStore - Compound Indexes - datastore-indexes - not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I am unable to search entities using compound indexes. I am using Objectify 4.

Entity configuration:

```
@Entity
@Unindex
class MyEntity implements Serialiable
{
    @Id String id;
    String one;
    String two;
    long three;
}
```

Index configuration:

```
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">
    <datastore-index kind="MyEntity" ancestor="false">
        <property name="one" direction="asc" />
        <property name="two" direction="desc" />
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

I see the indexes built in `DataStore Indexes`. However, when I search using the following query, I always get empty results.

```
Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.ofy();
Query<MyEntity> query = ofy.loader()
                           .type(MyEntity.class)
                           .filter("one", "value-one")
                           .filter("two", "value-two");
List<MyEntity> result = query.list();

response.getWriter().println("Size: " + result.size());
//^^ this is always "0" ^^
```

I'm using HRD.

Any guesses what's going wrong? btw, it used to work until some time back... as early as last week. Now, it doesn't work on dev-server as well as on actual servers.

Comment: Just to add, running the GQL on the sever also returns zero results. `SELECT * FROM MyEntity where one='value-one' and two='value-two'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compound indexes needs all properties involved to be indexed:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity implements Serialiable
{
    @Id String id;
    @Index String one;
    @Index String two;
    long three;
}
```

As you are saving the entities without marking the fields as indexed, Objectify is saving those entities without INDEXING them on those fields, thats why your GQL command also return 0 results.

Comment: IIRC, that was not the case earlier, or was it?

Comment: This has always been the case. There is a discussion on the issue tracker about this: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4231

Comment: I guess, that's due to change in Objectify. Earlier, the default was "Indexed" which changed to "Unindexed".