# Does composite index also create normal indexes?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have a requirement where I need to filter by propA and fitlter and sort by propB but never have to do just either propA or propB. I asked to not index propA and propB and created a compound index on both. But that didn't work.

As per [App Engine DataStore - Compound Indexes - datastore-indexes - not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510574/app-engine-datastore-compound-indexes-datastore-indexes-not-working)

a composite index also requires specifying the component props to be indexed. Does that mean, internally there will be 5 indexes, one for the compound index and 2 each (asc/desc) for the two props? I am trying to understand the storage requirements of a compound index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the individual properties `propA` and `propB` have to be indexed as well.

But no, you don't have to explicitly have to create (asc and desc) indexes for them, just let the datastore automatically create the built-in indexes for them (one per property, not 2) by simply not declaring them "not indexed". From [Indexes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes):

> ***Built-in indexes***
>
> By default, a Datastore mode database automatically predefines an
>   index for each property of each entity kind. These single property
>   indexes are suitable for simple types of queries.

So there will be 3 indexes in your case, 2 built-in and 1 composite.